# EBay Finding API internal server error

Tags: ebay-api

I'm testing eBay Finding API, specifically, the findItemsByKeywords call. The site is :
     http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/build-test/test-tool

But when I execute the findItemsByKeywords call, I'm getting an internal server error response. I'm tempted to think that eBay server is down, but that seems unlikely.

Could it be because of some restrictions of the sandbox account? Appreciate any input, I'm so stuck now. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction for Finding APIs in sandbox mode for sure.

I have tried API test tool with my developer account for FindItemsByKeywords. Its working fine for me.